# inputType="textMultiLine" not working with imeOptions="actionSend"?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

As topic says, is it not possible to use inputType="textMultiLine" with a EditText which uses imeOptions="actionSend" ? Why must it be set to only  inputType="text" ? Is there any work-around to solve this? Never used this before so I am kinda new to it. /Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use imeOptions="actionsSend", it converts the enter key into send key and hence there is no enter key in the keypad. So it is not possible to use multi line text.